# Spring/GitHub/Docker - Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: spring, docker, github

I'm new to Docker. Probalby I'm doing something stupid. When I build my project localy, I can run it without problems with docker. My project is configured as follow:

> application.properties

```
spring.application.name=dockertest
server.port=8081
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.meyenberger.webapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockertest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dockertest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>meyenbergerwebapps</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

So I configured a automatic Docker build when I push code to the GitHub repo. When I do `docker pull meyenbergerwebapps/dockertest` and `docker run -p 8081:8081 -t meyenbergerwebapps/dockertest` I always get the following error `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar`. What I'm doing wrong? When I do it manually, it works.

I followed this guide **https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/** and I can't see a difference. Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you doing a build of your maven project (ex: mvn package) prior to the build of the docker image (docker build)? Maybe it works in your local environment because the target is always there. But, as a good practice, sure you have not versioned your target directory

Answer (score 0):

From the error I think that the path to your Jar files is unreachable.
Are you sure you are metioning the write path to your jar files ? 
Could you try this ?
`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"," jar","app.jar"]`